# Swap Utilization Increase with Oracle Coherence

Tags: linux, swap

We are using Oracle Coherence on linux servers. However, we noticed that because of Coherence processes running, often our swap utilization % increases too much, sometimes becoming more than 98%, even touched 100% a few times.

Once we kill all the coherence related processes, then it becomes normal.

Is there any way we can make coherence processes to only use a particular size of Swap space ?

Currently increasing swap space is not in our scope.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid swapping, you will need to add more physical RAM.

If your application (Oracle Coherence) demands a large amount of RAM as a part of normal operation (i.e. not a memory leak), and you do not have enough physical memory, then pretty much the only option is swapping.

As a workaround, you might want to swap to a file, though this can be slower.

1. Create an empty file using `dd`: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/swapfile bs=1M count=<size, in megabytes>`.
2. Create a swap filesystem on it: `mkswap /path/to/swapfile`
3. Swap on it: `swapon /path/to/swapfile`.

Comment: Is there any way of restricting any process to only use a % of the swap space ? Since its a corporate system, for quick fix, RAM upgrade might take few days. We need to do quick fix.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't. And if you could do that, the kernel would kill the application as it runs out of memory. As a workaround you might want to swap to a file.

Comment: Oh okay. Yeah, we guys could not even SSH to those servers when it increased to 100%